# Package not found on custom launcher - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, app-launcher

I'm producing a custom app launcher in Android Studio using online tutorials, however, whenever I decide to run my application on the built-in emulator it never finds the cannot find the app I am trying to launch/package despite having the correct package name. Any help on this will be much appreciated however I am very very new to Java and Android Studio so keep it simple please thanks!

I've attached my code:

```
package com.android.myapplication;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int view = R.layout.activity_main;
    TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(view);
        final LinearLayout parent = findViewById(R.id.parent);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.text);
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.youtube");
                if (launchIntent != null) {
                    startActivity(launchIntent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There is no package available in android", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get an exception thrown or something? Can you provide us with that?

Comment: As far as I'm aware there is not, if you want any other logs I can give you them

Comment: Did you include all your imports in the above MainActivity class? Because I can see your package name on top but I can't see R import anywhere?